# can i change image and swf file in js?

Tags: javascript, image

I want to change an image after some seconds.

I have this code that works fine with images:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var x = 0,
        images = [
        "images/product/8f0165121827ee27e9ae4645988e3742.png",
        "images/product/f227c25f3cc58ab2af04a5da27879f17.png"
    ];

    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];
        if (x<1) {
            x+=1;
        } else if (x=2) {
            x=0;
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
<img id='ad' type='text' src="images/product/8f0165121827ee27e9ae4645988e3742.png" />
```

The problem is that I have one image and one swf file.

Can I change the code to change the image and swf file at specific time?

Answer (score 0):

To incorporate an SWF file, your best bet would be to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).
It is a simple open-source Javascript library that is easy-to-use and standards-friendly method to embed Flash content. Then place this in the body of your HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    images = new Array;
    images[0] = "images/product/8f0165121827ee27e9ae4645988e3742.png";
    images[1] = "images/product/f227c25f3cc58ab2af04a5da27879f17.png";

    setInterval(function() {changeImage()},1000);
    x = 0;
    function changeImage() {
        if (x<2) {
            document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];
            x+=1;
        }
        else if (x == 2) {
            swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
            x+=1;
        }
        else {
            x=0;
        }
    }
</script>
<img id='ad' type='text' src="images/product/8f0165121827ee27e9ae4645988e3742.png" />
```

With myContent.swf being the name of the SWF file you want to add. A good tool to use along with this is the SWFObject HTML and Javascript [generator](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/generator). It basically generates the HTML and Javascript you need to embed the Flash using SWFObject.

Answer (score 0):

@Pies I also recommend using swfObject. However, Flash can accept most media files directly as a parameter. If you're already using flash on your page, and you know it exists, you can send an image or a swf file to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
</head>
<bod>
  <div id="ad"></div>

  <script language="javascript">
  images = new Array;
  images[0] = "https://media.giphy.com/media/wLrdNV4YclpmM/giphy.gif";
  images[1] = "http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/SWF/test.swf";
  setInterval(function() {changeImage()},4000);
  var x = 0;
  var el = document.getElementById("ad");
  function changeImage() {
    swfobject.embedSWF(images[x], "ad", 600, 300, "10.0.0", null,{ bgcolor:"#000000" });
    x+=1;
    if (x > images.length-1) {
      x=0;
    }
  }

  changeImage();
  </script>
</body>
```

I'd have fiddled this, but it seems jsfiddle blocks swfObject.

Comment: seems to play, but i have 2 questions, with that code image and swf should have the same size, 600 width and 300 height,can i give them seperate size? and something else, i dont want bgcolor, i want trasparent, can i manage this?

Comment: sure, just make your array multi dimensional and pass the parameters into the swfobject.